# How to connect 3 diffrent micro services in nodejs to api gateway with kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, api-gateway

There is three micro services in node such as

- ms-application
- ms-authentication
- ms-notification

Now I want to connect this appplication to **api-gateway** with **kafka**.

How to connect these applications to one api-gateway.

How to call these micro-services in api-gateway with kafka !

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use asynchronous messaging between the gateway and the microservices?  Because the usual communication between these is HTTP.

Comment: API gateway for all the microservices request call through this gateway.                             actually, it is a requirement !! Even I Don't know how to connect this application with Kafka. I Made a simple gateway.js and registory.json file it's working But I want to connect with Kafka too.

Comment: Then read the KafkaJS documentation and try to follow the examples there

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS isn't relevant.
Kafka has its own TCP protocol, and clients must connect directly to the brokers. Therefore, it's unlikely your requests will traverse the API gateway.

More specifically, Kafka would be behind the gateway, not need to exposed

```
HTTP -> Gateway -> microservice <-> Kafka
```

Comment: As per the suggestions I made an API gateway Now how can I connect with Kafka to the API gateway? Made a registery.json file that defines all the services in it and its port. And the gateway is running on another port. It's working well! Can you help me @OneCricketeer with this stuff?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by having some JSON file, but Kafka isn't an HTTP service, so doesn't need to be part of the gateway. Your requests will route to a particular service, then each service can decide to use Kafka directly. You don't need to traverse the gateway once data is produced directly to brokers... You start a consumer in another service, then it'll start reading the topic